# How to handle DROP TABLE if there is a view on a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

`View` can be dropped using the `DROP VIEW` command. Is there a solution for handling `DROP TABLE` if there is a view on a table?

I tried like

```
DROP TABLE ORDER_TBL CASCADE;
```

Is there another way in a modern [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database#Terminology_and_overview)?

Comment: No - why? This **drops the table** - what more do you need/want??? Any views that depend on it will become invalid.

Comment: ok so need to use CASCADE for what i want to achieve or else no need of CASCADE?

Comment: No, CASCADE won't help - you just need to know what views or procs depend on a table, and drop or modify those. There's nothing in SQL Server to do this automatically for you - it's up to you to do this manually.

Comment: exactly it will become invalid without any warning right ? so is there any way to handle it

Comment: You need to know your database and know what views and/or stored procs need to be updated/dropped along with your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

If you run this script before `DROP TABLE`, it lists all objects that have a reference on your table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT so.name,so.xtype
FROM syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.id=so.id
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%YOUR TABLE%'
```

If you want just views, you can filter the above query by `AND s.xtype='V'`.

**Option 2 :**

You can add [WITH SCHEMABINDING](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/coding-dotnet/schemabinding-option-in-views-14746) to the definition of your view so you can not drop based table.

Answer (score 3):

Per the MSDN documentation:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790.aspx
>
> Any view or stored procedure that references the dropped table must be
>   explicitly dropped by using DROP VIEW or DROP PROCEDURE.

In other words, MSSQL doesn't automagically warn you, or drop the view for you.  The view simply becomes invalid.

MSDN continues:

> To report the dependencies on a table, use
>   sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities.

For example:

- http://sqlserverdownanddirty.blogspot.com/2011/07/finding-object-dependancies-in-sql.html

  SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, is_schema_bound, [definition]
  FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('mySchema.myTable', 'OBJECT') r
  INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m
  ON r.referencing_id = m.object_id

Comment: exactly it will become invalid without any warning right ? so is there any way to handle it ?

Comment: @ashuthinks - well, you can query for any dependencies with the above SQL before you drop the table :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Using SQL Search **before** you drop your table, you can find out what other objects are relying on that table. You'll need to deal with those in some ways - remove a dependency or drop those objects as well along with your table.

Comment: No need for an external tool. Right clicking the table in SSMS has a Dependencies menu.

Comment: @iDevlop: yeah - but SQL Search is **much better** and way nicer to use!

Comment: in some corporate environments, installing something on a server can be very difficult and a sure way to have big trouble.

Comment: @iDevlop: you don't have to install **anything** on the **server** - it's a client-only tool - just on your own workstation....

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to import a dump and the "user" table was already there. Drop table did not work:

> ERROR 1965 (42S02): 'mysql.user' is a view

In MySQL you can do:

`drop view user;`

This removed the table and no "drop table" was necessary, solving my import problem.